# Uninstalling the Sun java application server problems

Tags: java

I installed the sun java application server and am have a big problem. After I installed the application a menu option folder "Sun Microsystems" was added to my All Programs. After the installation it seemed that all of the options were installed except for the actual application server. I ran the uninstall menu option and now the "Sun Microsystems" menu option folder is still on the All Programs list and except the main folder no menu items appear except for the sub folder "Application Server PE" and in it the contents display (empty). Also, after reading several posts it indicated I need several key values from the registry should be removed. After looking at the registry the options key value indicate (default), (value not set). Now when I go back and retry to install the application server again I receive the error "Could not find the required version of the java(TM) Runtime Environment.

I am really stuck and need help bad. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try and reinstall the JDK/JRE first. Maybe you messed up the registry keys where the JDK/JRE installer saves the installed java version.

The required keys should look something like this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.5\JavaHome]
```

You should try and install the JDK (not the JRE) if you're planning to develop applications, btw.

Comment: OK. so I did what you recommended and when I try to run sjsas_pe-8_2-Windows.exe I get the error "Could not find the required version of the Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment (Indicates it must be higher).. Now, under programfiles\java I do have the following installed directories: jdk1.8.0_60, jre1.8.0_60

Comment: Can you try with the latest installer for application server?  I see it's 9.1, and you're trying with 8.2, maybe it's not compatible with jdk8 or smth. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-archive-downloads-glassfish-419424.html)